# Why doesn't my chat filter check words correctly?

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make some kind of chat filter. I also wanna check for `"wo rd"` or `"w ord"` or even `"w.ord"` . But if I enter "word wo rd" , it outputs `"**** **** ****"` (should be `"**** ****"`). Also, even if I disable `dot` checking, it ignores dots..

Here is my code:

```
    //Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NotAllowedWords.Add(new WordData("word", true, false));
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var splitted = input.Split(char.Parse(" "));
            foreach (string s in splitted) {
                var index = FindWord(input,s);
                if (index != -1) {
                    input = input.Replace(s, "****");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }

        private static int FindWord (string input, string word) {
            var splitted = input.Split(char.Parse(" "));
            bool next = false;
            foreach (var w in splitted) {
                foreach (var a in NotAllowedWords) {
                    if (a.CompareTo(word)) 
                        return input.IndexOf(word);
                }
                if (next) {
                    next = false;
                    if (w.Substring(0, word.Length - 1) == word.Substring(1)) 
                        return input.IndexOf(w);
                }
                if (w.Last() == word[0])
                    next = true;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static List<WordData> NotAllowedWords = new List<WordData>();
    }

    public class WordData {

        protected WordData() {
            IgnoreWhiteSpace = true;
        }

        public bool CompareTo(string word) {
            var input = word;
            if (this.NotAllowDots) {
                input = input.Replace(".","");
            }
            if (this.IgnoreWhiteSpace) {
                input = input.Trim();
            }
            if (input.Equals(input, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !this.AllowedVersions.Contains(input))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public WordData(string word, bool ignoreWhiteSpace = true, bool notAllowDots = true, params string[] allowedVersions) : base() {
            this.allowedVersions = allowedVersions.ToList();
            this.IgnoreWhiteSpace = ignoreWhiteSpace;
            this.NotAllowDots = notAllowDots;
            this.Word = word;
        }

        public string Word { get; set;}

        private List<string> allowedVersions = new List<string>();

        public List<string> AllowedVersions {
            get {
                return allowedVersions;
            }
        }

        public bool IgnoreWhiteSpace { get; set;}

        public bool NotAllowDots {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Input : `word wo.rd wo rd`
Output : `**** **** **** ****`
Expected Output : `**** word ****`

Comment: Looks like you have 4 words in your input, since you split on (" ") space. "word", "wo.rd", "wo","rd".

Comment: @MarkLarter Oh, yes; my logic though :). How can I avoid that?

Comment: @MarkLarter Also, dot disable doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered using RegEx ? you can construct dynamic regular expression for your not allowed words , there you will be able to replace string parts using regex expression without needing to split it using " ".  with your current method a space has meaning depending on where it is positioned in the input that makes it difficult .

Comment: @DannyD Any tutorials or examples?

Comment: You might need to take a closer look at the existing logic. The input "There is a word in here somewhere!" produces output "**** **** **** **** **** **** somew****!", which is not at all what you describe wanting. I don't think the current approach will work out. A different way might use char arrays, and walk start to finish matching character-by-character.

Comment: @MarkLarter lol that output is cool though. But I dont want to use char arrays because I dont want to check exactly same.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz  see posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it with regex . you can use this online tool to test different patterns http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var notAllowedWord= new NotAllowedWord("word");

        var input = "replace word  wo.rd also wor d and wor.d but not wordpress .";

        var replacedText = notAllowedWord.ReplaceNotAllowedWord(input);

        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);

        //output
        //replace **** ****also ****and ****but not wordpress .

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public class NotAllowedWord
    {
        private readonly string _word;
        private readonly Regex _wordRegEx;
        private readonly string _replacement;

        public NotAllowedWord(string word)
        {
            _word = word;
            _replacement=new string('*',word.Length);
            _wordRegEx = BuildRegExPattern();
        }

        private Regex BuildRegExPattern()
        {
            //TODO USE string builder                
            var pattern = "";

            //create space and . match pattern  
            // example given "word" it will produce "w[ ]*\.*o[ ]*\.*r[ ]*\.*l[ ]*\.*d"
            foreach (var c in _word)
            {
                pattern = pattern + c + @"[ ]*\.*";
            }

            var regex = $"({_word}[ ])" + //Match the word
                    $"|({pattern}[ ])" + //match word that contains space or .
                    $"|({pattern}$)"  //match word that is at end of a sentence
                    ;

            //Console.WriteLine(regex);

            return new Regex(regex);
        }

        public string ReplaceNotAllowedWord(string inputText)
        {
            return _wordRegEx.Replace(inputText, _replacement);
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. But wo.rd doesnt have space after it seems.